# solib-absolute-prefix vs. solib-search-path in GDB

Tags: gdb, kgdb

I read the description of both but I don't yet understand the difference. Can anyone help me understand the differences?

```
set solib-absolute-prefix -
Specifies the local directory that contains copies of target libraries in the 
corresponding subdirectories. This option is useful when debugging with gdbserver.
```

.

```
set solib-search-path command - 
Specifies directories where GDB will search for shared libraries with symbols. This option        
is useful when debugging with gdbserver.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The wording is quite unclear :-(

Assume that your target loaded `/usr/lib/libfoo.so`, and that on the host (where GDB is running), you have a copy of the entire target tree in `/tmp/host`. That is, a copy of target's `/usr/lib/libfoo.so` is found on host in `/tmp/host/usr/lib/libfoo.so`.

Then, the following commands are almost equivalent:

```
set solib-absolute-prefix /tmp/host
set solib-search-path /tmp/host/usr/lib
```

Now consider what happens if you also have `/usr/local/lib/libbar.so` on target, and a copy of it in `/tmp/host/usr/local/lib/libbar.so`.

The `solib-absolute-prefix` as set above is still good to locate `libbar.so`, but `solib-search-path` would have to be modified like so:

```
set solib-search-path /tmp/host/usr/lib:/tmp/host/usr/local/lib
```

To summarize, *if* you have *entire* target tree under a single host `$ROOT`, then just set `solib-absolute-prefix` to `$ROOT` and you should be good.

But *if* you have to "assemble" target paths from multiple disjoint trees, then `solib-search-path` with multiple paths will allow GDB to still find correct libraries.